# What is the best way to transfer data over the network with confirmation. .Net

Tags: c#, .net, client-server, transfer, confirmation

I write a client-server application. I have some data structures that I want to send via network from client to server. I present them as byte array of determined size. Server and client know about this structure.

My aim is to send a groups of structures and wait for confirmation from server that they were received and saved properly on its side..

My idea was to create a simple code.

Client side:

1. connect to server;
2. prepare a list of structures;
3. in a loop send them as byte arrays to network using Stream.Write(...) method. Then Flush();
4. wait for server response about how much data it could save.
5. repeat all from step 2.

Server side:

1. accept client connection;
2. receive data till the end (Stream.Read() doesn't want to determine the end of data may be because the connection is still alive);
3. save all data to disk;
4. send response about amount of saved data to client using the same client connection which was used to obtain data from client.

Problem was that at the server side I couldn't determine the end of data group sent by the client.

how to do all what I want wright?

Comment: have you looked at C# Socket programming.. what type of data are you trying to transfer over the network. will this be TCP/IP, Named Pipes, Sockets, Threads / Multi-Threaded ..etc.. good question you have but you have not provided the type of data thats to be transfered.. thanks

Comment: My original data is a  bunch of structures. Before sending I convert them into byte arrays and transfer them using NetworkStream class.

Comment: Kraze already asked some interesting facts about the data. Additionally you should tell whether performance is an issue. It looks like a simple WCF-Service would suffice for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I forgot to say that I cannot use WCF because if it uses .net newer than 2.0 that I should use in my circumstances.

Comment: Yes, perfomance is very important.

Comment: it is some type of event registration system, structures represent events in this system and must be transferred as fast as it possible

Comment: I don't have it complete yet, but as it happens I'm working on a high performance fully async message based (`byte[]` based) multi-binding, multi-client server that I plan on releasing as OSS. Once it is stable, and assuming the OSS plan doesn't change, you'd be more than welcome to use it.

Comment: How soon it may be completed?

Comment: @yurart hmmm... just noticed your 2.0 requirement; the server I'm putting together uses a 3.0 API for the scalable async network sockets

Answer (score 2):

It sounds to me that the issue is the `Flush()` not doing anything - which is actually the documented behaviour for `NetworkStream.Flush()`:

> The Flush method implements the Stream.Flush method; however, because NetworkStream is not buffered, it has no affect on network streams. Calling the Flush method does not throw an exception.

To get around this; I would configure your socket to send **immediately** (set `NoDelay` to `true`), and then to avoid issues with packet size, I would wrap the `NetworkStream` in a `BufferedStream` (noting that a single buffered stream is only good for **either** read **or** write, but not both at the same time). Then:

- write, write, write etc to the `BufferedStream`

  - whenever it is full it will write to the network, sending immediately
- flush the `BufferedStream`

  - which will write to the network, sending immediately

this will allow the end of your message to be sent without getting stuck in the output buffer, and without requiring you to close the stream.

Comment: I cannot try right now but I'll try to do in in the near future. Thanks

Comment: @yurart no, there are no deleted comments

Answer (score 0):

**Edit** : OP has now added the comment proviso that he needs to use pre .NET 3.0.

Provided that both ends of the connection are .NET, WCF should have all the tools you ever need to control the transfer of data.

More specifically, have a look at

- [Streaming](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733742.aspx)
- [Transaction Flow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733116.aspx)

Also, if you ever need to switch to asynchronous data transfer, you can change to a [queued transport like MSMQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789048.aspx).

Comment: I've said about WCF higher. I'll take a look at MSMQ a little bit later. Thanks

Comment: You might be able to save yourself a ton of dev and debugging time by upgrading to .NET 4?

Comment: I understand, but our sowtware must work on old machines with windows 2000 that does not accept .net 3.0 as far as I can remember

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn't you use MSMQ? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms978430.aspx

Comment: I think it's may be I haven't heard about it. I'll take a look, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I used .Net Remoting to perform data transfer tasks. So, problem is solved (if there are no others will appear:) )